# how to get ISO8601 format in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, swift3

I am using amazon web service for items search. i can able get time stamp value and  i converted into iso format. but in console output it shows **Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format**

Here is my full console output value : 
**status code is: Optional(400)
     XML: 
      . 
     `InvalidParameterValue`Value 2018-06-15T18%3A43%3A52Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.66a698a6-a967-4b34-b15a-94780f9287ce**

here is the coed i tried for :

```
    public func getSearchItem(searchKeyword: String) -> [String:AnyObject]{
      let timeStamp = getTimestamp()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IST")
    let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: timeStamp.string(from: Date()))!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print("EXACT_DATE : \(dateString)")

    let url = "http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["Service": "AWSECommerceService",
                                  "Operation": "ItemSearch",
                                  "ResponseGroup": "Images,ItemAttributes",
                                  "SearchIndex":"All",
                                  "Keywords": searchKeyword,
                                  "Timestamp": urlEncode(timeStamp.string(from: date)),
                                  "AWSAccessKeyId": urlEncode(ViewController.kAmazonAccessID),
                                  "AssociateTag": urlEncode(ViewController.kAmazonAssociateTag)
                                 ]



    let signedParams = signedParametersForParameters(parameters: parameters as! [String : String])

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: signedParams, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        .responseString { response in
            print(" - API url: \(String(describing: response.request!))")   // original url request
            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                if let string = response.result.value {
                    print("XML: \(string)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                statusCode = error._code // statusCode private
                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                print(error)
            }
    }


    return parameters as [String : AnyObject]
}

func getTimestamp() -> DateFormatter{
    var timestampFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timestampFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timestampFormatter.dateFormat = AWSDateISO8601DateFormat1
    timestampFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IST")
    timestampFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return timestampFormatter
}
```

}

Comment: `2018-06-15T18%3A43%3A52Z` I'm wondering if the issue is about the ":" percent escaped (transformed into "%3A"), because else `2018-06-15T18:43:52Z` seems valid to me. So if just do `"Timestamp": timeStamp.string(from: date)` instead of `"Timestamp": urlEncode(timeStamp.string(from: date))`?

Comment: @Larme can you add it has a answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error being:

```
Optional(400) XML: . InvalidParameterValue Value 2018-06-15T18%3A43%3A52Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.
```

The issue is about the `:` percent escaped (transformed into `%3A`), because `2018-06-15T18:43:52Z` seems valid in ISO8601 format while `2018-06-15T18%3A43%3A52Z` doesn't.

You are adding yourself the percent escape in `parameters`:

So:

```
"Timestamp": urlEncode(timeStamp.string(from: date))
```

=>

```
"Timestamp": timeStamp.string(from: date)
```

Also, note that in iOS there is a [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) available from iOS10+ that could avoid you writing the format yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
func convertDateToDateString(date: Date, format: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_EN")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)

    let resultDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return resultDate
}
```